# PHPickerview result will not load videourl

Tags: swift, xcode, video, phpickerviewcontroller

I'm trying to get the video URL (video chosen from user camera roll) from PHPickerview result, however I'm receiving this error: It's saying that it can't load representation of type public.movie, hence the file won't be opened since it doesn't exist. This only happens with larger video files. :/

I've already tried using different type identifiers, and it hasn't worked.

> Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.movie" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.movie, NSUnderlyingError=0x282932ca0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/E5CE1DB9-85C1-4378-94C2-D384E92C5268/File Provider Storage/photospicker/version=1&uuid=B42E6922-E10A-46DB-8B95-66B009F7294A&mode=compatible.mov, NSLocalizedDescription=The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist.}}}

```
result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier)
{ videoURL, error in
                    
  assert(Thread.isMainThread == false)

  let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
  let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString.appending(".mov")

  if let videoURL = videoURL,
    let copiedURLFile = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [directory, fileName]) {
```

Comment: Your code needs to check the error first, and print it out and then stop.

Comment: @matt my error is printing out, what do you mean? I want to know how to fix the error being presented in the print statement.